# JQuery autocomplete with auto generated textbox

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i am trying to add the autocomplete plugin to a textbox generated inside my jquery code as part of a table, but i get nothing. Here's my code:

```
var spool = "<thead><tr><th>Α/Α</th><th>Ονομασία Ύλης</th><th>W/W%</th><th>Κωδ.Ύλης</th><th>Σχόλιο</th><th>Χρήση Συγκεκριμένης Ύλης</th><th>Ορθή Αναλογία</th><th>Ορθή Χρέωση</th><th>Ιδιοκτησία Ύλης</th><th>Προτεινομενος Προμηθευτής</th></thead>";
spool += "<tr><td>1</td><td><input type ='textbox' id = 'ingautotb' style = 'margin-left: -1px;margin-right: -1px;margin-top: -1px;margin-bottom: -1px;border: 0px;'></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>"
var a = ['a','av'];
$('#ingautotb').autocomplete({source:a});
```

Comment: where is `spool ` used?

Comment: Can you put your original HTML markup ?

Comment: Here the problem is you are calling `$('#ingautotb').autocomplete({source:a})` before the input element is added to the dom

Comment: You were right, i added the autocomplete, after adding the table to the DOM and it worked. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, you are trying to create autocomplete widget using an input element which have not yet added to the dom.

Try

```
var spool = "<thead><tr><th>Α/Α</th><th>Ονομασία Ύλης</th><th>W/W%</th><th>Κωδ.Ύλης</th><th>Σχόλιο</th><th>Χρήση Συγκεκριμένης Ύλης</th><th>Ορθή Αναλογία</th><th>Ορθή Χρέωση</th><th>Ιδιοκτησία Ύλης</th><th>Προτεινομενος Προμηθευτής</th></thead>";
spool += "<tr><td>1</td><td><input type ='textbox' id = 'ingautotb' style = 'margin-left: -1px;margin-right: -1px;margin-top: -1px;margin-bottom: -1px;border: 0px;'></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";

//insert spool to dom ex
//$('#mycontainer').append(spool)

var a = ['a','av'];
$('#ingautotb').autocomplete({source:a});
```